# AgoraRtcKit.muteLocalAudioStream not working?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to mute speaker using `muteLocalAudioStream(true)` in `AgoraRtcKit`. After calling this method orange indicator is still on a device.

How can I mute user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my question. In order to stop/resume publishing the local audio stream (mute/unmute) we need to call  `AgoraRtcEngineKit.enableLocalAudio(isEnabled)`

For more details visit [official Agora documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/oc/Classes/AgoraRtcEngineKit.html?platform=iOS#//api/name/enableLocalAudio:)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

First get rtcEngine object then try to mute it

```
var rtcEngine: AgoraRtcEngineKit!
rtcEngine.muteLocalAudioStream(true)
```

Comment: Actually I have the exact same code, but it does not work. Orange indicator is still on after executing these lines.

Comment: adjustPlaybackSignalVolume

Set this to 0 

Then try again

Comment: It did not work